# Predict if sites returns the same content

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, urllib2

I am writing a web crawler, but I have a problem with function which recursively calls links.
Let's suppose I have a page: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind`.
I am looking for all links, and then open each link recursively, downloading again all links etc.
The problem is, that some links, although have different `urls`, drive to the same page, for example:
`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#mw-navigation`
gives the same page as the previous link.
And I have an infinite loop.

Is any possibility to check if two links drive to the same page without comparing the all content of this pages?

Comment: `http://somepage` and `http://somepage#something` IS the same page. Everything after the hash sign is a link to an anchor at that page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 1):

You can store the hash of the content of pages previously seen and check if the page has already been seen before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make extra requests to the same page.

You can use [`urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and check if the `.path` part of the base url and the link you crawl is the same:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urlparse import urljoin, urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind"
base_url = urlparse(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        url = urljoin(url, link['href'])
        print url, urlparse(url).path == base_url.path
```

Prints:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#mw-navigation True
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#p-search True
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Set_partitions_4;_Hasse;_circles.svg False
...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation False
...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind True
...
https://www.mediawiki.org/ False
```

This particular example uses [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the wikipedia page and get all links, but the actual html parser here is not really important. Important is that you parse the links and get the path to check.

Comment: Thanks, it is really helpful, because I am using both: urlparser and BeautifulSoup in my program